# Is this function decreasing in $x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, integral-inequality, error-function

Consider
$$x \mapsto \frac{\int_{x-b}^{x+b} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2} }\text d z}{\int_{x-c}^{x+c} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2} }\text d z}$$
decreasing in $x\in [0,\infty)$, if $c > b > 0$ ?

What I tried:

taking the derivative in $x$ yields:

$$\frac{\left( e^{-\frac{(x+b)^2}{2}} - e^{-\frac{(x-b)^2}{2}} \right)\int_{x-c}^{x+c} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\text d z - \left( e^{-\frac{(x+c)^2}{2}} - e^{-\frac{(x-c)^2}{2}} \right)\int_{x-b}^{x+b} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\text d z}{\left( \int_{x-c}^{x+c} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\text d z \right)^2} $$
where the sign is determined by the numerator, so the question is if

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{(x+b)^2}{2}} - e^{-\frac{(x-b)^2}{2}}}{e^{-\frac{(x+c)^2}{2}} - e^{-\frac{(x-c)^2}{2}}} - \frac{\int_{x-b}^{x+b} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2} }\text d z}{\int_{x-c}^{x+c} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2} }\text d z} \geq 0 \ ?$$

Comment: Why not applying Leibnitz rule?

Comment: I tried to consider the derivative. But even in "explicit" form I think  its sign is hardly to determine (I have not managed it). So maybe someone else has another idea.

Comment: It makes sense, intuitively, that it is decreasing. As $x$ increases, the slices of $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ get smaller.

Comment: Yes, but also the denominator is decreasing. But you can easily verify that the function tends to $0$ when $x\to \infty$. Further, you see that at $x=0$ there is an extrem value.

Comment: It seems that the last inequality whoud have the opposite sign, because $ e^{-\frac{(x+c)^2}{2}} - e^{-\frac{(x-c)^2}{2}}<0$.

Comment: The equality for the derivative is equivalent to that for a fixed $x$ a function $f(b)=\frac{e^{-\frac{(x+b)^2}{2}} - e^{-\frac{(x-b)^2}{2}}}{\int_{x-b}^{x+b} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2} }dz}$ is non-decreasing for $b>0$ and the computer experiments suggest that this is true.

Comment: It might help to first tackle the case when $c$ is an integer multiple of $b$. That way, the denominator turns into a sum of shifted copies of the numerator, which might simplify matters. Then you could tackle the case when $c$ is a rational multiple of $b$, and finally appeal to some continuity argument to get the full statement.

Comment: Try using the estimates $(y-x) e^{-y^2/2} \leq \int_x^y e^{-z^2/2} \, dz \leq (y-x) e^{-x^2/2}$.

Comment: @Alex Ravsky: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me just show you a few tricks so the next time you'll be able to figure such things out without pen or paper, not to mention MSE.

First, drop the common part. We need to show that 
$$
x\mapsto \frac{\int_{[x-b,x+b]}e^{-z^2/2}dz}{\int_{[x-c,x+c]\setminus[x-b,x+b]}e^{-z^2/2}dz}
$$ 
is decreasing for $x\ge 0$.

Next, use symmetry and the fact that the integral of a family of decreasing functions over the parameter is still a decreasing function. Thus, it suffices to show that for every $0<s<b$,
$$
x\mapsto \frac{e^{-(x-s)^2/2}+e^{-(x+s)^2/2}}{\int_{[x-c,x+c]\setminus[x-b,x+b]}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz}
$$ 
is decreasing for $x\ge 0$.

Turn the fraction upside down and use the same logic to conclude that it suffices to show that for all $0<s<b<t$, 
$$
x\mapsto \frac{e^{-(x-t)^2/2}+e^{-(x+t)^2/2}}{e^{-(x-s)^2/2}+e^{-(x+s)^2/2}}
$$ 
is increasing for $x\ge 0$.

Now open parentheses and cancel inessential stuff. We just need to show that for $0<s<t$,
$$
x\mapsto \frac{e^{xt}+e^{-xt}}{e^{xs}+e^{-xs}}
$$ 
is increasing for $x\ge 0$.

This can be done by hand, but here is a general principle that makes it a no-brainer. Let $f(x)=\sum_{k\ge 0}a_k x^k$ and $g(x)=\sum_{k\ge 0}b_k x^k$. If $a_k,b_k\ge 0$ and $a_k/b_k$ increases with $k$, then $f(x)/g(x)$ increases for $x\ge 0$. Indeed, let $\mu=f(x)/g(x)$ for some $x$. Then $0=f(x)-\mu g(x)=\sum_{k\ge 0}(a_k-\mu b_k)x^k$. Note that the coefficients $a_k-\mu b_k$  must change sign just once from $-$ to $+$ as $k$ increases. Let them change sign between $K$ and $K+1$. Then, if we replace $x$ by $x'>x$, all negative terms will be multiplied by at most $(x'/x)^K$ while all positive terms will be multiplied by at least $(x'/x)^{K+1}$, so the difference $f(x')-\mu g(x')$ will be positive.

The rest should be clear.

Comment: Took me a while to verify all your steps. The last part I have done by hand. Somehow I do not understand how your general principle can be apllied here.
By the way, it seems to be crucial to make use of the symmetry as you did. I tried it first without this symmetry argument, cause the resulting quotient is simpler. But then it does not work in the end.

Comment: @Falrach "I do not understand how your general principle can be apllied here" We have $f(x)=e^{xt}+e^{-xt}=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2k}}{(2k)!}(x^2)^k$ and similarly for the denominator $g(x)$ with $s$ instead of $t$. Thus $a_k/b_k=(t/s)^{2k}$ (if you view $x^2$ as a new variable), which is clearly increasing. The symmetry is crucial, indeed :-)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help